# React Next js app redirect to login is premature

Tags: reactjs, next.js

After a lot of searching for several hours, I have the following code to redirect from a user profile page if not logged in.

NOTE: Simply showing a not authorized page is easy but its the redirect thats messing things up.

The code does the job of redirecting when user is not logged in.

```
const Dashboard = () => {  
  const [user, { mutate }] = useCurrentUser();
  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    // redirect to login if user is not authenticated
    if (!user) router.push('/login');
  }, [user]);
...
```

The **problem** is when a **user is logged in** and directly goes to /user/dashboard route, for a split second, user is undefined may be so it redirects to login. When it gets to login, it finds that user is authenticated so redirects to home page because I am redirecting a logged in user to home page.

How to prevent that split second of "not a user" status when page is first loading?

I tried -

1. getInitialProps
2. getServerSideProps - Cant use router because next router can only be used on client side
3. componentDidMount - UseEffectI tried above is the equivalent correct?

Edit: Based on answer below, I tried this but still directly takes user to login first. I am using react cookies and I do see loggedIn cookie as true when user is logged in and its not set when user is not logged in.

```
Dashboard.getInitialProps = ({ req, res }) => {
  console.log(req.headers.cookie)
  var get_cookies = function(request) {
    var cookies = {};
    request.headers && request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
      var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/)
      cookies[ parts[1].trim() ] = (parts[2] || '').trim();
    });
    return cookies;
  };

  //console.log(get_cookies(req)['loggedIn']);

  if (get_cookies(req)['loggedIn'] == true) {
    console.log("entered logged in")
    return {loggedIn: true};
  }
  else {
    console.log("entered not logged in")// can see this on server console log
  // User is not logged in, redirect.
  if (res) {
      // We're on the server.
      res.writeHead(301, { Location: '/login' });
      res.end();
    } else {
      // We're on the client.
      Router.push('/login');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my page is a child"? Afaik subroutes should still be able to use `getInitialProps`.

Comment: yes you are right. had to use `Dashboard.getInitialProps`. In that case I think I can use cookies to check logged in get/initialProps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of struggle, there was one number that was breaking this.

Instead of

```
res.writeHead(301, { Location: '/login' });
```

I used

```
res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/login' });
```

and it worked.

301 is a permanent redirect so if we use that, when the user logs in, the browser still holds the redirect cache.

**From next js docs**

Next.js allows you to specify whether the redirect is permanent or not with the permanent field. This is required unless you need to specify the statusCode manually

When permanent is set to true we use a status code of 308 and also set a Refresh header for backwards compatibility with IE11.

When permanent is set to false we use a status code of 307 which is not cached by browsers and signifies the redirect is temporary.

Next.js permits the following status codes:

```
-301 Moved `Permanently`
-302 Found
-303 See Other
-307 `Temporary` Redirect
-308 Permanent Redirect
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement redirect when not authenticated in **getServerSideProps**
Below example is based on JWT Authentication with cookies.

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    const cookie = ctx.req.headers.cookie;
    const config = {
        headers: {
            cookie: cookie ?? null
        }
    }
    let res;
    try {
        // your isAuthenticated check
        const res = await axios('url', config);
        return { props: { user: res.data } };
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        ctx.res.writeHead(302, {
            Location: 'redirectUrl'
        })
        ctx.res.end();
        return;
        return { props: { user: null } };
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, getserverside and getinitialprops both do not run for me when I refresh page. The approach works the first time but after that it does not work and has same behavior and there is a split second of user not logged in.

Comment: although getserversideprops did not work, I used your idea of cookies so voting up.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `getInitialProps` to redirect. You just need to check whether you're on the server or the client and use the proper redirect method. You can't use hooks in `getInitialProps` so your `useCurrentUser` approach won't work and you'll need some other way to check whether the user is authed. I don't know anything about the structure of your application, but it's probably just some kind of request to wherever you're storing the session.

```
import Router from 'next/router';

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  // props.user is guaranteed to be available here...
};

Dashboard.getInitialProps = async ({ res }) => {
  // Check authentication.
  // Await the response so that the redirect doesn't happen prematurely.
  const user = await ...

  // User is logged in, return the data you need for the page.
  if (user) {
    return { user };
  }

  // User is not logged in, redirect.
  if (res) {
    // We're on the server.
    // Make the redirect temporary so it doesn't get cached.
    res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/login' });
    res.end();
  } else {
    // We're on the client.
    Router.push('/login');
  }
};
```

Comment: thanks. update question with what I tried. cookies are setting correctly but still logged in users go to login screen for a split second. Not sure if its because getinitialprops does not work when I navigate directly to /dashboard

Comment: looks like its related to this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241387/getinitialprops-does-not-work-when-the-page-reload

Comment: The issue is that getInitialProps will only be called on the server-side on the first page load and then called subsequently when you click on Links (as stated in the next.js docs: https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle).
This means that if you use getInitialProps to evaluate logged in you will actually only have it set when it's not the first page load.

Comment: after many hours of debugging there was one number change in what I was doing earlier and then in your answer that was breaking this. 301 permanently caches the redirect. We do not need the redirect after the user logs in on the same computer so we need to use 307 - `res.writeHead(307, { Location: '/login' })`